# How to save/retrieve data with android device sd-card, via USB Debugging mode?

Tags: c#, android

Is there a way to save/retrieve files from an android device, via the USB debugging mode.
That means I want my application to get connected even if the Device is charging via the USB cable connected to the PC.

I think the ADB (Android Debug Bridge) is capable of rendering this service, however I am not quite sure if it works, If it does how can I use it with C# to simply save and get some files from the SD-Card

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADB can indeed accomplish that for you.

to pull a file from the device:

```
adb pull /mnt/sdcard/somefile.txt
```

to push a file to the device

```
adb push somefile.txt /mnt/sdcard/
```

(Note: obviously you'll need to replace `somefile.txt` with your own path and/or filename.)

I am not very familiar with C# but surely you could make something with that that can interact with the ADB binary to accomplish these tasks.

[See here for a more complete listing of ADB functionality / syntax](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)